# Push notification issue with python

Tags: python, linux, push-notification

I using plyer module in my code and i'm a linux user.

this is my very simple code :

```
from plyer import notification
 
notification.notify(
    title = "title",
    message="message",
    timeout=10
)
```

when i run this code i see this error :
NotImplementedError: No usable implementation found!

how can i fix it?

Some where i see it happen when your **libnotify-bin** package not install. but it was install and i update it. but i see this error again.

Comment: Ensure that you're using the latest version of the `plyer` library `pip install --upgrade plyer`